# Css element is being hidden by another element

Tags: html, css

I am adding tooltip for an element with current structure: https://jsfiddle.net/bielus86/08vbbLvw/1/

I cannot get `tooltip-cla` to appear on top of the page `div`.
Is there a way to add some css class for `tooltip-cla` element?

Ideally **I do not want to add any javascript code.**

```css
.mainNav {
  /* box-sizing: border-box; */
  height: 582px;
  margin-top: 80px;
  background: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  min-height: 82px;
  border: 1px solid #b2b2b8;
  border-left: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 500;
}

.wrapper {
  background-color: transparent;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 300px;
  left: 0px;
  display: block;
}

.tooltip-cla {
  color: #999777;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: auto;
  right: auto;
  top: -30px;
  bottom: auto;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 2px solid #444;
  padding: 16px;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainNav">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="tooltip-cla">Main header</div>
      Some text here
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Then you need to clarify what it is you are trying to achieve. It is not clear at the moment.

Comment: Just to clarify. I updated fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/bielus86/08vbbLvw/3/
I want to be able to see content inside tooltip-cla on page class. At the moment it is partially hidden behind it.

Comment: If the answer I posted helped you out or solved your query, make sure to rate or mark it up. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you just remove the `overflow: hidden` from mainNav and the `overflow-x: auto; overflow-y:auto;` from wrapper does that achieve what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Few things you need to know and rememeber:

- Absolute positioning works with relation to its immediate parent (The parent element generally has `position:relative` defined & then the child element `position:absolute`). In this case, your tooltip-cla in regards to the wrapper div. That's why no matter how you try to shift it up, it would but it won't show outside the parent container.
- To fix that issue, just change the position to "fixed" and top to "0", assuming you want it fixed on top of the page even while scrolling.
- In case, you want it at the top but need to scroll it while you scroll the page as well. You just need to take it out of your mainNav and use it at the top instead as a header.

> Referring to your JSfiddle, why are you making it complex by defining
>   the tooltip in wrapper when you want it in the page class? Just move
>   the tooltip class to the page class. You're making it more complex,
>   than needed.

```css
.mainNav {
  /* box-sizing: border-box; */
  height: 582px;
  margin-top: 80px;
  background: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  min-height: 82px;
  border: 1px solid #b2b2b8;
  border-left: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 500;
}

.wrapper {
  background-color: transparent;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 300px;
  left: 0px;
  display: block;
}

.tooltip-cla {
  color: #999777;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  left: auto;
  right: auto;
  top: 0;
  bottom: auto;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 2px solid #444;
  padding: 16px;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainNav">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="tooltip-cla">Main header</div>
      Some text here
  </div>
</div>
```